# Center text inside special indentation environment with \addtolength

Tags: debugging

I want to center the sentences "Firma del jurado" but `\begin{center}` doesn't work. How can I center these sentences?

```
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{0.5\textwidth}

Nota de aceptación:\newline\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\

\vspace{2cm}
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
Firma del presidente del jurado
\vspace{2cm}\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
Firma del jurado\\
\vspace{2cm}\\
\mbox{}\hrulefill\\
Firma del jurado

}
```

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\signatures}{%
  \begin{flushright}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \makebox[.5\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{1cm}\hrulefill} \\[1ex] % this sets the width
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[1ex]
  \hrulefill \\[2cm]
  \hrulefill \\
  \footnotesize Firma del presidente del jurado \\[2cm]
  \hrulefill \\
  \footnotesize Firma del jurado \\[2cm]
  \hrulefill \\
  \footnotesize Firma del jurado
  \end{tabular}
  \end{flushright}
}

\begin{document}

\signatures

\end{document}
```

I used the `showframe` package for producing the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\hfill\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{c}
    Nota de aceptación:\\
    \hspace*{0.5\textwidth}\\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \\\hline
    \vspace{2cm}\\\hline
    Firma del presidente del jurado
    \vspace{2cm}\\\hline
    Firma del jurado\\
    \vspace{2cm}\\
    Firma del jurado
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]